# How to perform Triple DES calculations in Ruby in hexadecimal?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, 3des

I'm trying to do some triple DES encryption in Ruby.  I'm trying to replicate the results from this page: http://da.nmilne.com/des.html

I'm trying to replicate those result in Ruby.  I suspect the problem is the key is supposed to be a string, but I need to pass in a Hexadecimal key. Either that or the string being encrypted is in the wrong format. Or maybe both. :-)

```
require 'openssl'
des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("des-ede-cbc")
des.encrypt
des.key="23232323232323234545454545454545"
des.update("0000000000000000")
res=des.final
res.unpack('H*')  
=> ["5045c5d37ca4d13b"]
```

But it should be:

```
=> ["3a42d7a1d1c60c40"]
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong?

- Different 3DES algorithms are documented here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html
- Edited for clarity

Comment: This page had some other useful information : http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/576

Comment: Are you expecting "2323..." to actually be 0x2323.. i.e. a hex number, or something similar?

Comment: Yes - but key= expects a string - not a number. I've also tried : des.key="23232323232323234545454545454545".unpack('a2'*32).map{|x| x.hex}.pack('c'*32) (Which was from the link in the first comment) but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in hex - if you look at the Java page you pasted you can see that easily by decoding the binary values for the key in the detailed output.

```
>> des_cbc=OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("des-ede-cbc")
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x10116ce28>
>> des_cbc.encrypt
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher:0x10116ce28>
>> des_cbc.key="\x23"*8 << "\x45"*8
=> "########EEEEEEEE"
>> des_cbc.update("\x00"*8).unpack('H*')
=> ["3a42d7a1d1c60c40"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why the key is "\x23"*8 and not "\x2\x3"*8?  Is it because \x operates on a byte?

Comment: Also - why is it \x and not 0x ?  And - why do you need to use '("\x00"*8).unpack('H*')' ? Is it to get binary 0, rather than the string/ascii values of "0" ? Man, I'm such a n00b with this binary / hex / decimal stuff.

Comment: "\x00" is hex null. Two nibbles per byte, which is also why it's "\x23" and not \x2\x3 (35 base 10). \x.. is a string version of 0x.. which would be a fixnum. Try it all out in irb. :)